# Laravel GET Request variables mixed up with url

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, laravel-request

Observing weird behaviour with the GET request in Laravel 5.7 Facebook Socialite login. Suddenly stopped working and here is what I have found:

1. At user click login with facebook redirect works correctly, comes back with `code` get variable in url to my callback function as such:

Request URL:

```
https://mysite.loc/callback?code=AQD3hC5MTa&state=TvFnYlXwfJsqKm6ZoDbC

Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
```

Query String Parameters

```
code: AQD3hC5MTaJe
state: TvFnYlXwfJsqKm6ZoDbC6I9IaIYWDT4vgvxxx3P4
```

So far so good, now to the weird stuff debugging in my callback function:

```
var_dump(\Request::input());
```

Produces:

```
array (size=2)
'//callback?code' => string 'AQD3hC5MTaJe' (length=344)
'state' => string 'TvFnYlXwfJsqKm6ZoD' (length=40)
```

Socialite expects code to be available under

```
 \Request::input('code')
```

Which is not in my case it is

```
\Request::input('//callback?code')
```

The most bizarre thing I ever seen. I am using NGINX on Docker running Linux. Route:

```
Route::get('/redirect', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@redirect');
Route::get('/callback', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@callback');
```

Function signature:

```
public function callback(SocialFacebookAccountService $service);
```

**UPDATE**

Nginx Vhost had:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?/$request_uri;
}
```

Updated to:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$request_uri;
```

That made things better, result of debug is now:

```
array (size=2)
'/callback?code' => string 'AQD3hC5MTaJe' (length=344)
'state' => string 'TvFnYlXwfJsqKm6ZoD' (length=40)
```

Notice one slash less at front of callback, but it still is truly there... Should just be the code and state variables. Any one can spot what am I doing wrong on the vhost? Looks stock standard...

I am stuck for ideas how to debug the request failure any further, obviously reluctant to change the Socialite code as well. Have tried to access via both query and input - same result...

**UPDATE**

Answer below is correct. Editing Nginx Vhost to reflect fixed the issue:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```

Incredibly any tutorial found online for setting up Nginx with Laravel has the wrong setting. Good to collect this info here.

Answer (score 2):

this is an issue with the redirection of the request to `public/index.php` of laravel.

it's either in the vhost declaration of nginx or in your .htaccess

basicly, it's getting `https://mysite.loc/callback?code=AQD3hC5MTa&state=TvFnYlXwfJsqKm6ZoDbC`

redirect it to

`https://mysite.loc/index.php?//callback?code=AQD3hC5MTa&state=TvFnYlXwfJsqKm6ZoDbC`

instead of

`https://mysite.loc/index.php/callback?code=AQD3hC5MTa&state=TvFnYlXwfJsqKm6ZoDbC`

ps: the using of the domain name and protocol in the redirection example `https://mysite.loc/` is just for clarification. nginx doest do that exactly

*Update*:
Here is what i'm putting in my nginx vhost

```
/index.php$is_args$args
```

Comment: Thank you N69S, giving an up vote! Spot on! Only issue is 1 forward slash still remains after vhost clean up - updated my question with clean up details!

Comment: @Vlad added an example in my answer